# How can I save a Microsoft Access database as .sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, ms-access

Are there any add-ons or something that can enable Microsoft Access to save its database as .sqlite?

Or do you know of any other way I can convert them, both ways.

Thanx a lot

Comment: Unfortunately they are completely different, both the program language and the SQL syntax, even if you track down an app I feel this would be better to do manually.

Comment: this is pretty much duplicated i believe..

Comment: Please don't keep asking the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9924311/how-can-i-convert-my-access-database-accdb-to-a-sqlite-database-sqlite

Comment: See also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7657115/how-to-convert-mdb-to-sqlite-database-in-android

Answer (score 0):

If you can find an application (libreoffice?) or language with bindings/reader to access or if you can convert the access "db" into something sane, it shouldn't be too difficult to go to sqlite from there. The code you need will probably be specific to your particular database and not a universal Access->sqlite converter.

Actually, you might see if access could directly talk to sqlite over ODBC. Longshot, but that might be closest to a full answer to your question.

You could see these, for starters:

- [What do I need to read Microsoft Access databases using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853370/what-do-i-need-to-read-microsoft-access-databases-using-python)
- [how to deal with .mdb access files with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620539/how-to-deal-with-mdb-access-files-with-python)
- [SQLite Syntax Error In Union Select Query From MS-Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8329513/sqlite-syntax-error-in-union-select-query-from-ms-access)
- [How to use sqlite database from inside MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513121/how-to-use-sqlite-database-from-inside-ms-access)
- ODBC/JDBC resources
- Bindings and libraries for your favourite languages